# batch script /findstr function to echo only the left of the delimiter

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, findstr

I want to get only the filename inside the text file containing ".PDF"

**Expected output:**

```
PP_12345.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.18 
PP_23456.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.18 
PE_12345.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30 
PE_23456.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30
```

Information inside the test.txt

```
put PP_12345.pdf some text here
DOC ID 11223344555
put PP_23456.pdf some text here
oopps this is a sample
ls PP*.pdf
put PE_12345.pdf some text here
this is a sample sentence
ls PE*.pdf
put PE_23456.pdf some text here
```

Here is my code:

```
set Logtext="PP"
set Logtext1="PE"
set findfile="test.txt"

FOR  /f "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('findstr %Logtext% %findfile%') DO echo  %%A %DATE% - %TIME% >> log.txt
FOR  /f "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('findstr %Logtext1% %findfile%') DO echo  %%A %DATE% - %TIME% >> log.txt
```

Here is the result of log.txt:

```
 put PP_12345 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.18 
 put PP_23456 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.18 
 ls PP* 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.18 
 put PE_12345 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30 
 ls PE* 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30 
 put PE_23456 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q43752174.txt"
set "Logtext=PP"
set "Logtext1=PE"
REM set "findfile=test.txt"

FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=. " %%a IN ('FINDSTR /L /i /c:"%logtext%_" /c:"%logtext1%_" "%filename1%"^|find /v "*"') DO IF /i "%%c"=="pdf" (
  ECHO %%b.%%c %DATE% %time%  
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q43752174.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This assumes that the filenames you seek are all preceded by *word*<kbd>Space</kbd> and none contain "P?_" elsewhere than as starting characters

---

edit : added extra "find" filter to exclude asterisks.

Comment: Yes, that is the actual information of the text file. Thanks it works perfectly.

Comment: one more thing, I see some file containing  
`ls PE_*.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30`
`ls PS_*.PDF 03/05/2017 - 13:56:32.30` I also need to  exclude those